# Determine protocol of a network drive

Tags: c#, windows, network-protocols

Is there a way to determine the protocol name (SMB/CIFS,NFS) and version that is used for a mounted network drive on windows? (in C#)

**EDIT**

Using info from Rusted's answer, i got the following information from a windows 7 computer on the network.

```
NETRESOURCE res = WinApiWNETwrapper.GetResourceInfo("\\Test-PC");

res.dwDisplayType = SERVER
res.dwScope       = 0
res.dwType        = ANY
res.dwUsage       = CONTAINER
res.lpComment     = ""
res.lpLocalName   = null
res.lpProvider    = "Microsoft Windows Network"
res.lpLocalName   = "\\Test-PC"

NETINFOSTRUCT netinfo = WinApiWNETwrapper.GetNetworkInfo("\\Test-PC");

netinfo.cbStructureSize   = 32
netinfo.dwCharacteristics = 0
netinfo.dwDrives          = -1
netinfo.dwHandle          = 1880621056
netinfo.dwPrinters        = -1
netinfo.dwProviderVersion = 1024
netinfo.dwStatus          = Running
netinfo.wNetType          = LANMAN

SERVER_TRANSPORT_INFO_1[] transports = WinApiNETwrapper.ServerTransportEnum_1("\\Test-PC");

transports[0].svti1_domain                 = "WORKGROUP"
transports[0].svti1_networkaddress         = "TEST-PC"
transports[0].svti1_numberofvcs            = 0
transports[0].svti1_transportaddress       = 73107336
transports[0].svti1_transportaddresslength = ...
transports[0].TransportAddress             = "TEST-PC"

transports[0].svti1_transportname          = "\\Device\\NetbiosSmb"
transports[1].svti1_transportname          = "\\Device\\NetBT_Tcpip_{F4C75115-...}"
transports[2].svti1_transportname          = "\\Device\\NetBT_Tcpip_{70BD9048-...}"
```

The important part seems to be:

```
transports[0].svti1_transportname          = "\\Device\\NetbiosSmb"
```

But i cannot find the version number of the SMB protocol anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you've need the [Windows Networking (WNet) API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a value from NetType field in [NETINFOSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returned by [WNetGetNetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385461%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/netcommander/) is open-source project in C#, check files in [WnetApi](http://code.google.com/p/netcommander/source/browse/#svn/trunk/WnetApi) folder for .NET wrappers for Wnet API.

To get the UNC path for a mapped drive use PathToUNC method from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=2939) project.

Comment: This was big help! Looking at the source of the mentioned c# project i  managed to get some info about a network computer. But I still do not have the protocol version. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I think netinfo.wNetType = LANMAN in your result means SMB protocol, because enum names in C# wrapper was taken from old version of  Winnettwk.h. I have checked C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\wnnc.h - it contains a new name with same value: #define     WNNC_NET_SMB         0x00020000