# Detect SMB vs SMB2 for network share

Tags: windows, winapi, osx-mavericks, smb, cifs

Given a UNC path like `\\server\share`, is there any way to determine, using the Win32 API, whether the local and remote computers are connecting using SMB or SMB2?

Comment: Check this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800616/determine-protocol-of-a-network-drive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After burning a paid support incident, the official answer from Microsoft is that this information isn't exposed by the driver in Windows 7.  On Windows 8 it's available using WMI and the [MSFT_SmbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830461%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, or PowerShell's `Get-SmbConnection` cmdlet.

Comment: Win10 PowerShell's `Get-SmbConnection` cmdlet required admin shell for me. worked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find the answer in the SMB2 specification.

[Server Message Block (SMB) Protocol Versions 2 and 3 specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246482.aspx)

There should be a way to detect the version... Maybe you can try to implement a minimal part of the SMB protocol just to ask the server the protocol version?

Answer (score 0):

one of the easyest way to find is by taking a network trace using the wireshark (on windows) or tcptrace/tcpdump on the unix (where SMB is running). The trace output should give you the version

Comment: I'm looking for something that we can detect dynamically at program startup for arbitrary servers that our customers are connecting to.  Using a packet sniffer or debugger won't work.